# How can I get the UUID of the paired phone from the Watch App - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, watchkit, apple-watch

I would like to get the UUID of my paired phone from the watch app.
Can I get the details of the phone.

Comment: you cant get uuids anymore.

Comment: To clarify, you can no longer get the *UDID*, which may well be what the OP is asking for. But if it's some sort of other identifier, then, well, who knows, we need more information in order to answer this question.

Comment: If i may have mis stated I am talking about the https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor @cekisakurek

Comment: I know this is for the iPhone but I want to get the vendor identifier for the paired phone from the watch app @cekisakurek

Answer (score 0):

you can get the vendor id and save it to user defaults and retrieve it on watch app

on main app

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] forKey:@"vendorId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and then on watch app

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"vendorId"];
```